# Pass Where Operators to Backend with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How can I pass [Op.Between] and other Op conditions from my frontend to my Express/Sequelize REST API backend? The frontend features a user interface allowing for advanced filtering and searching. So I'm hoping to just build the JSON on the frontend post it to the backend.

Pseudo function on backend.

```
async function findComments(req, res, next) {
  const rows = await comments.findAll(req.body);
  res.status(200).send(rows);
}
```

Pseudo call from the frontend.

```
body = {timestamp: {[Op.Between]: [1658797156, 1658858168]} 
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/comments', 
        method: 'post', 
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
```

Comment: This might not work because Op is not defined in the Frontend. You can refer to a layered architecture like MVC to solve this issue. Instead of directly sending the request body to the data layer (here Squelize function) you can process data accordingly and add any Op conditions. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/model-view-controllermvc-architecture-for-node-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea: you can define all the OPs that you want as an `enum` in your backend and give each one of them a `code` or `id` and then make your frontend send that code that corresponds to the specific `OP` in the request.